# How do I get from Nice to Haut de Cagnes by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, france, nice

How do I get from Nice to Haut de Cagnes using public transportation? Also, it seems pretty close; is it a good idea to visit during the day while staying in Nice, or should I stay the night in Haut de Cagnes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cagnes-sur-Mer has a railway station, with frequent trains from Nice (generally every half hour). Trains take about 15 minutes, and you just buy the ticket at the station on departure. Depending on where you are in Nice [bus 94](http://www.lignesdazur.com/horaires_ligne/?rub_code=6&part_id=&lign_id=1118&sens=2) might be useful too. The local bus company has its website here: http://www.lignesdazur.com/ (Press the British flag for English).

Generally speaking:

- Getting there by public transport is easy and cheap.
- Doing it as a day trip perfectly feasible.

Haut de Cagnes is about 1km from the train station. If you really don't want to climb, you can walk to the town center (square Bourdet, also a stop on bus 94) and take [bus 44](http://www.lignesdazur.com/horaires_ligne/index.asp?rub_code=6&lign_id=57) uphill.

Comment: Thanks Krist. Is Cagnes the same as Haut-de-Canges? (or Cagnes-sur-Mer?) I want to go 'up the hill' into the old town. Do I need a bus for that?

Comment: @NelsBeckman Cagnes = Cagnes-sur-Mer > Haut-de-Cagnes. Haut des Cagnes is simply the areas near the cliffs where the castle is.

Comment: The train frequency is more every hour to every half hour (it is every half hour at peak times).

Comment: The train frequency really is every half hour throughout the day (according to the timetable), with even a few extra trains at peak times, with the exception of one 1 1/2 hour window in the early afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up doing:

- I took the train to the Cagnes-sur-mer railway station.
- I walked about 10 minutes from the train station to the shuttle stop (because we couldn't for the life of us find a cab). [Walking directions](http://goo.gl/maps/MVZNT)
- We took shuttle 44 up to the chateau.